# Deploying with Flightplan and Bower

Tags: node.js, express, digital-ocean

I am trying to deploy a small nodejs project to Digitalocean using Flightplan. More or less everything works fine. However, I have 3 issues regarding Bower:

1) When I deploy with the "fly" command `bower.json` seems to get ignored and not pushed to the server.

2) When running `bower install` on my VPS it doesn't create a src folder but puts bower_modules into the app's root folder. This brakes my `express.static` command.

3) How should I change my flightplan.js file to automate bower install?
I tried this but it throws an error

```
  remote.sudo('npm --production --prefix ~/' + tmpDir + ' install ~/' + tmpDir, {user: username});
  remote.sudo('bower ~/' + tmpDir + ' install ~/' + tmpDir, {user: username});
```

This is my .gitignore file (as far as I know flightplan respects it when deploying?)

```
node_modules/
src/bower_modules
```

Comment: For #2 put a `.bowerrc` in your directory http://bower.io/docs/config/

Comment: #3 what is the error thrown?

Answer (score -1):

I am using this:

```
remote.exec('cd /home/deploy/'+tmpDir+'; ' +'ls'+';'+'bower install');
```

It works for me.